# How to Transform from xml to json in Azure Logic apps using Liquid

Tags: azure, liquid, azure-logic-apps

I am using the Transform XML to JSON.
This is my request body in XML

```
<Root>
<test>
    <column1>value1</column1>
    <column2>value2</column2>
</test>
<test>
    <column1>value1</column1>
    <column2>value2</column2>
</test>
</Root>
```

and this is my liquid map

```
{
    "test": [
        {% for data in Root.test %}
        {
            "column1": "{{data.column1}}",
            "column2": "{{data.column2}}",
        }
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

while running the logic app i am getting parsing error:

```
{
  "Code": "IncorrectLiquidTransformOutputType",
  "Message": "An error occurred while converting the transformed value to JSON. The transformed value is not a valid JSON. 'After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered: {. Path 'test[0]'"
}
```

But while I run the same code in the liquid sandbox is working fine. may I know? what is the issue here with logic apps.

Comment: Do you need a comma after the closing '}' inside the for loop?

Comment: I want the response to be in json. That's why tried like that

Comment: And array elements are separated by commas in JSON, which doesn't appear to be present in this example.

Comment: Hi @JeganRaj May I know if the solution I provided works ? If it helps your problem, could you please mark my answer as accepted, thanks in advance~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I test it in my side and provide my liquid map below for your reference:

```
{
    "test": [
        {% for data in content.Root %}
        {
            "column1": "{{data.column1}}",
            "column2": "{{data.column2}}"
        },
        {% endfor %}
    ]
}
```

Run this liquid map and it works fine(shown as below screenshot)
[image]

Hope it helps~

Answer (score 0):

I'll summarise the answers/comments already provided as I didn't see the issue when I first checked the accepted answer!

This type of error can be caused by missing out a comma at the end of a JSON object literal that you want to be repeated as elements in the array, in the transformed output.

**Fails**

```
[
    {% for data in Root.test %}
    {
        "column1": "{{data.column1}}",
        "column2": "{{data.column2}}",
    }
    {% endfor %}
]
```

**Works**

```
[
    {% for data in Root.test %}
    {
        "column1": "{{data.column1}}",
        "column2": "{{data.column2}}",
    },
    {% endfor %}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use if condition to add "," `{% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}`

```
{
"test": [
    {% for data in content.Root %}
    {
        "column1": "{{data.column1}}",
        "column2": "{{data.column2}}"
    }{% if forloop.last == false %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
]}
```